# How can I "extend" this Mohawk to reach both sides of part of a helmet?

Tags: particles

It's kind of hard to describe... How can I "extend" this Mowhawk look with the hair particles, mainly without affecting the geometry?

[image: The Goal]

Comment: I would consider using the comb in ortho-side view, as adjusting the faces from which the hair is growing would change the look of the middle part of your model.